# Stored Procedure is too slow (using CURSOR )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, cursor, linked-server

I have the below code to insert the unprocessed (`processed=0`) records from server 1 to server 2 (using linked servers), and once inserted it should be updated to `processed=1`

I was just using

**Query 1:**

```
INSERT INTO SELECT FROM WHERE processed=0
UPDATE processed=1 WHERE processed=0
```

**Query 2:**

```
DECLARE pending_records CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT FROM WHERE processed=0

OPEN pending_records

FETCH NEXT FROM pending_records INTO @UniqueID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO SELECT FROM WHERE UniqueID=@UniqueID

IF @@ROWCOUNT=1 .... UPDATE processed=1 WHERE UniqueID=@UniqueID

FETCH NEXT FROM pending_records INTO @UniqueID

END

CLOSE pending_records

DEALLOCATE pending_records
```

Query 1 is super fast and Query using cursor is too slow ( takes 30 seconds to updates 1 records)

I stay away from Query 1 because if there is any failure in database, it will effect the records. Note: I cannot use `DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` right now because it needs additional setup.

Comment: `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM WHERE`... Table names can be made up if you're afraid we will still them from you. The very least you can do is put together a sample that can compile.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can. I just noted one thing now, without the `IF @@ROWCOUNT=1 .... UPDATE processed=1 WHERE UniqueID=@UniqueID` it takes only 3 seconds to complete 400 records. With the update command, it takes nearly 15 minutes ( for 400 records)

Comment: So please [edit] your question so that we can see code that makes sense. Also, it would probably help if we knew what table is on what server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Or can I just use `WHILE (count(*) from table > 0), Update top 1....`

Comment: Why are you using a cursor for these updates? You do not want to use a cursor here because as you have discovered the performance is horrible. If you only want to capture those that were processed you should use an output clause in your insert statement to a temp table and then use that temp table in an insert statement.

Comment: I found the issue. It is related with Linked Server and Update Command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712611/very-slow-sql-update-using-a-linked-server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the 'FAST_FORWARD' argument?

The 'FAT_FORWARD' specifies the FORWARD_ONLY, READ_ONLY cursor with performance optimizations enabled. FAST_FORWARD can not be specified if SCROLL or FOR_UPDATE is also specified.

Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180169(v=sql.120).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: add an extra column to your table where you put an extra processing-flag. Generate a GUID at the beginning of your stored procedure and update your table:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET processing_flag = <GUID>
WHERE processed = 0;
```

And then you can simply transfer your rows to the other server by

```
INSERT INTO <target>
SELECT <columns>
FROM <source>
WHERE processed = 0 AND processing_flag = <GUID>;
```

After this you can set processed = 1 and erase the processing_flag. If something Fails you can select all not transfered rows by processed = 0 and processing_flag != NULL.

I had a similar problem with transfering single rows. By putting them all in one my problem was solved.

Maybe your target-server or the connection is too slow too.

Comment: I cannot modify the table, it is used by a third party application.

Comment: Can you add a new table?

Comment: What kind of datatype is processed?

Comment: For testing it is varchar(10), for live it will be date. `unprocessed` will be `NULL`, and `processed` will be with a date

Comment: Let me ask one question: Why you cannot modify the table, because it's used by a 3rd party application, and then you write for testing it's varchar(10) and live date?